# MahApps Flyout Closebutton still showing after collapsing it

Tags: wpf, vb.net, mahapps.metro

After creating a flyout, and setting `CloseButtonVisibility="Collapsed"`I set the background color for the grid to aqua... showing that the close button margin is still there.

This is how I create the flyout..

```
<Controls:Flyout Name="PingFlyout"
                             IsModal="True"
                             CloseButtonVisibility="Collapsed"
                             Theme="Light"
                             Position="Top"
                             Margin="250,100,250,100"

                             AnimateOpacity="True"
                             AnimateOnPositionChange="True" 
                             />
```

[image]

Am I missing something? How do I get rid of the close button area completely and have my flyout actually center?

Comment: Which MahApps version do you use? Cause this should be fixed since 1.3.0

Comment: I'm currently using 1.4.3

Comment: Set `TitleVisibility="Collapsed"` too to hide the `Flyout` title completely.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`TitleVisibility="Collapsed"` in addition to `CloseButtonVisibility="Collapsed"`hid the margin.